# How to get the exact weights and threshold used by a Neural net (Matlab Neural Network)

Tags: matlab, neural-network

After training and testing a neural net on Matlab, I got a satisfactory Net-output.

The problem I am facing now is how to get the weights/bias distributed by the network, as well as the threshold, as I intend to use them on a different program.

I just need a guide on how to retrieve these values from the network

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The weights are saved in the [`network`](http://mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/network.html) class. The values are contained in

```
net.IW
net.LW
net.b
```

where `net.IW` contains the input weight values, `net.LW` contains the layer weight values and `net.b` contains the bias values.

To help you with the implementation of the neural network, you could use [`genFunction`](http://mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/genfunction.html) to create a MATLAB function for your neural network.

Comment: thanks for your response. When I used net.b, I got `[20X1 double][4X1 double][3X1 double]`. Can you help interprete what that means? thanks.